# How to move custom cursor over a text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, custom-cursor

I have made a custom cursor but it is not working properly over text(p, h1, button, span). Here is the code

html:

```
<!-- custom cursor -->
<div class="cursor"></div>
```

js:

```
    const cursor = document.querySelector(".cursor");

    document.addEventListener("mouseover", (e) => {
        cursor.style.left = e.pageX + "px";
        cursor.style.top = e.pageY  + "px";
        console.log(e.pageX, e.pageY); // i checked pageX and pageY values also not change when cursor moves over a text or button

     })
```

css:

```
.cursor{
    position: fixed;
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #ffffff38;
    transition-duration: 0.16s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.16s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.16s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.16s;
    transition-timing-function:ease;
    -o-transition-timing-function:ease;
    -moz-transition-timing-function:ease;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function:ease;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    pointer-events: none;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
    /* display: none; */
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

It is working fine over links. Can you tell me how can i make the cursor to move smoothly(over all text and buttons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`mouseover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event) event triggers when you move your mouse over an element - but it doesn't keep triggering when you move the mouse inside that element.

Have you tried [`mousemove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousemove_event) instead?

Comment: Thank you.  it worked. I was using wrong listener

Answer (score 0):

I think below code will help you. There are some mistakes in your code like background color of cursor `background-color: #ffffff38;`, this is white which can't be seen in white page. And also I hide the original cursor.
In JavaScript code you have used `mouseover` which will trigger every time when your mouse enter the specific area, you should use `mousemove`, it will trigger everytime when you move your mouse.

```js
const cursor = document.querySelector(".cursor");

document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  cursor.style.left = e.pageX + "px";
  cursor.style.top = e.pageY + "px";
  console.log(e.pageX, e.pageY);
  // i checked pageX and pageY values also not change when cursor moves over a text or button

})
```

```css
html{
  cursor: none;
}
.cursor {
  position: absolute;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  z-index: 10000;
}
```

```html
<!-- custom cursor -->
<div class="cursor"></div>
```